# Phonegap 3.3 installation issues

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, android-studio

I'm having some issues with the new phonegap installation, using nodejs. I've managed to get everything working, set the path to ant, android sdk, java jdk etc., everything works perfectly.

With the usage of the following commands I've managed to create a new project:

> cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

However, when I've examined the project, it was empty:

[image]

So I went into the "hello" folder and added an Android platform in the following manner:

> cordova platform add android

and then I've build it:

> cordova build android

So, after that, there were some android specific folders, as shown below:

[image]

Is this how the structure is suppose to look like? I'm having REAL problems importing this into Android Studio. However, I managed to import the project into eclipse, but now I have two projects, first is named "HelloWorld" and the other "HelloWorldCordovaLib". This is a bit confusing. While it works, why are there two projects? Am I doing something wrong?

Moreover, when I import this project into android studio, I get a bunch of errors (whereas the same project works in eclipse): [Errors with the structure](http://shrani.si/f/K/UX/3VtMIcSc/androidstudio.png)

This is seems very, very confusing. I have yet to understand why Phonegap is suddenly so hard to install. I hope I'm missing something. Any kind of feedback is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: They are not projects actually,they are two modules inside one project and its fine. This is the way Android Studio project structure is .have you tried to run the project ?

Comment: I have in eclipse and it works, but in android studio it doesn't. if you can please check the link you'll see that several things were not imported in android studio and because of that, the app cannot be run,

Comment: have you tried them to move manually in your helloWorldCordovaLib ?

Comment: How exactly could I do this?

Comment: create a respective package under src dir of Library and copy paste all the classes which are not copied.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Here's the structure of the project in http://shrani.si/f/47/uE/2Jn41yZx/eclipse.png (eclipse), which works and here's the http://shrani.si/f/R/NH/30yFxypG/as.png (android studio version), which doesn't work. As you can see, and as android studio lets me know: "Android Gradle projects use a different directory structure than ADT Eclipse projects." What exactly am I to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio, amazingly, can't import Android projects that don't have the Gradle project structure. Until Cordova starts generating Gradle files, or Android Studio completes the importer's types of projects it'll support, you have to export the project from Eclipse before you can import it in to Android Studio.

It's perfectly valid to have two Projects in one Cordova application.  Usually, it's because your app references the Cordova project as a sort of "sub-project" (not the right term, but I'm not sure what Android calls it).

Answer (score 0):

The structure is correct.
when giving the command `cordova platform add android` you are actually adding a folder named `android` inside platform folder. For android development you have to work on the files inside `platforms/android`.

Read more here [Phonegap - Command line interface](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

Comment: Thanks, I've figured this much and the project works in Eclipse if I import it, but it doesn't work in Android Studio..